# More Efficient DataTable Sorting

Tags: c#, algorithm, datatable

I parsing some .nessus files and I have worked out a way to use a `temp` table (`dtNessusFindings`) to store values. Before a value is added to the `temp` table I check my `perm` storage (`FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable`).

Finally, I ensure that the only findings left are unique based on pluginID and pass/fail (`ConsolidateFindings()`), since it's possible for one pluginID to pass on workstationA but fail on workstationB.

The purpose of the 2 tables is to perform a lookup on the `perm` storage so that I can consolidate `hostnames` and avoid manually consolidating the findings later.

My question, is that using the following class it takes over 14 minutes to parse the data. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Dixie
{
public class NessusParseLinqXMLConsolidated : MasterFindingsTable
{
        private static DataTable dtNessuFindingsTable;

        public static void ParseNessusXML(List<string> fileNames, string radioResultHost)
        {
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            foreach (string doc in fileNames)
            {
                files.Add(doc);
            }

            if (FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable == null)
            FindingsFactory.InitializeNessusFindingsTable();

            dtNessuFindingsTable = new DataTable();                                  //Column Number
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("testID", typeof(string));              // 0
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("passFail", typeof(string));            // 1
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));         // 2
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("vulLevel", typeof(string));            // 3
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("recommendation", typeof(string));      // 4
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("comments", typeof(string));            // 5
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));               // 6
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("testCheck", typeof(string));           // 7
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("source", typeof(string));              // 8
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));                // 9
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("hostName", typeof(string));            // 10
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("os", typeof(string));                  // 11
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("ipAddr", typeof(string));              // 12
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("stigLevel", typeof(string));           // 13
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("stigSeverity", typeof(string));        // 14
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("sarStatus", typeof(string));           // 15
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("iaControl", typeof(string));           // 16
            dtNessuFindingsTable.Columns.Add("key", typeof(int));

            int key = 0;
            List<string> missingHostnames = new List<string>();
            bool noHostName = false; //automatically assume hostname exist

            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                XElement xelement = XElement.Load(s);
                IEnumerable<XElement> findings = xelement.Elements();

                var findingDetails = from f in findings.Descendants("ReportItem")
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         title = f.Element("plugin_name").Value,
                                         description = f.Element("synopsis").Value,
                                         vulLevel = f.Element("risk_factor").Value,
                                         fixText = f.Element("solution").Value,
                                         testID = f.Attribute("pluginID").Value
                                     };
                var hostDetails = from hd in findings.Descendants("tag")
                                  .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system")
                                  select hd.Value;

                var os = findings.Descendants("tag")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                if (os == null)
                {
                    os = findings.Descendants("tag")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "os")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                }
                var hostname = findings.Descendants("tag")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "host-fqdn")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                var ipAddress = findings.Descendants("tag")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "host-ip")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                var dateTime = findings.Descendants("tag")
                    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "HOST_END")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                if (hostname == null)
                {
                    missingHostnames.Add(s.ToString());
                    noHostName = true;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < findingDetails.Count(); i++)
                {
                    foreach (var fd in findingDetails)
                    {
                        bool exists = FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable
                            .Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["testID"].ToString() == fd.testID.ToString());

                        bool exists2 = dtNessuFindingsTable
                            .Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["testID"].ToString() == fd.testID.ToString());

                        if (exists | exists2)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow dr in FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable.Rows)
                            {
                                if (dr["testID"].ToString() == fd.testID.ToString() && dr["passFail"].ToString() == "pass")
                                {
                                    if (hostname != null && !dr["hostname"].ToString().Contains(hostname))
                                        dr["hostName"] = dr["hostName"].ToString() + ", " + hostname;
                                    else
                                        dr["hostName"] = hostname;
                                }
                                else if (dr["testID"].ToString() == fd.testID.ToString() && dr["passFail"].ToString() == "fail")
                                {
                                    if (!dr["hostname"].ToString().Contains(hostname))
                                        dr["hostName"] = dr["hostName"].ToString() + ", " + hostname;
                                    else
                                        dr["hostName"] = hostname;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows.Add();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["testID"] = fd.testID.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["title"] = fd.title.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["vulLevel"] = fd.vulLevel.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["description"] = fd.description.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["recommendation"] = fd.fixText.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["source"] = "Tenable Nessus Pro";
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["ipAddr"] = ipAddress.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["date"] = dateTime.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["os"] = os.ToString();
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["passFail"] = GetPassFail(fd.vulLevel.ToString());
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["stigSeverity"] = GetSTIGSeverityLevel(fd.vulLevel.ToString());
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["sarStatus"] = GetSarStatus(GetPassFail(fd.vulLevel.ToString()));
                            dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["key"] = key;
                            if (noHostName == true)
                                dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["hostname"] = "Add <tag name=\"host-fqdn\">hostname to use</tag> to file: " + s.ToString();
                            else
                                dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["hostname"] = hostname;

                            i++;
                            key++;
                        }                      
                    }
                }
                noHostName = false;
                for (int i = dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    //remove empty rows from table
                    if (dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i]["testID"] == DBNull.Value)
                        dtNessuFindingsTable.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
                dtNessuFindingsTable.AcceptChanges();
                FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable.Merge(dtNessuFindingsTable, false);
            }
            DataTable dtFinal = ConsolidateFindings(FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable).Copy();
            FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable.Clear();
            FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable = dtFinal.Copy();
            FindingsFactory.NessusFindingsTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
        private static DataTable ConsolidateFindings(DataTable dtOrginal)
        {
            DataTable tblresult = dtOrginal.Clone(); // empty table, same columns
            var rowGroups = dtOrginal.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => new
                {
                    Id = row.Field<string>("testId"),
                    passFail = row.Field<string>("passFail")
                });

            foreach (var group in rowGroups)
            {
                DataRow row = tblresult.Rows.Add(); // already added now
                row.SetField("testId", group.Key.Id);
                row.SetField("passFail", group.Key.passFail);
                row.SetField("description", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("description")).First());
                row.SetField("vulLevel", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("vulLevel")).First());
                row.SetField("recommendation", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("recommendation")).First());
                row.SetField("comments", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("comments")).First());
                row.SetField("title", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("title")).First());
                row.SetField("testCheck", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("testCheck")).First());
                row.SetField("date", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("date")).First());
                row.SetField("os", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("os")).First());
                row.SetField("ipAddr", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("ipAddr")).First());
                row.SetField("stigLevel", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("stigLevel")).First());
                row.SetField("stigSeverity", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("stigSeverity")).First());
                row.SetField("sarStatus", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("sarStatus")).First());
                row.SetField("iaControl", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("iaControl")).First());
                string source = String.Join(", ", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("source")));
                row.SetField("source", source);
                string hostNames = String.Join(", ", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("hostname")));
                row.SetField("hostname", hostNames);
            }
            return tblresult;
        }
       public static string GetSTIGSeverityLevel(string riskLevel)
       {
            string stigSeverityLevel = null;
            switch (riskLevel.ToLower())
            {
                case "high":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "I";
                    break;
                case "very high":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "I";
                    break;
                case "critical":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "I";
                    break;
                case "moderate":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "II";
                    break;
                case "low":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "III";
                    break;
                case "very low":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "IV";
                    break;
                case "none":
                    stigSeverityLevel = "N/A";
                    break;
            }
            return stigSeverityLevel;
        }
        private static string GetPassFail(string riskFactor)
        {
            string status = null;
            if (riskFactor.ToLower() == "none")
                status = "pass";
            else
                status = "fail";
            return status;
        }
        private static string GetSarStatus(string passFail)
        {
            string sarStatus = null;
            switch (passFail.ToLower())
            {
                case "critical":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "very high":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "high":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "low":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "moderate":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "medium":
                    sarStatus = "Other than Satisfied";
                    break;
                case "n/a":
                    sarStatus = "N/A";
                    break;
                case "none":
                    sarStatus = "N/A";
                    break;
            }
            return sarStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be this double loop

```
            for (int i = 0; i < findingDetails.Count(); i++)
            {
                foreach (var fd in findingDetails)
                {
```

and the easiest fix would be to replace it with this

```
            int i = 0; 
            {
                foreach (var fd in findingDetails)
                {
```

Comment: are you suggesting replacing the `foreach` with a `for` loop? Or vice versa?

Comment: @Chris pick one or the other but not both. The `foreach` would be better because of the deferred execution of the `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Chris I am suggesting removing one of the loops not replacing it. Also, you should profile or time parts of the code to see what parts are the slowest.

Comment: wow, so that worked! I thought the loops were what was slowing it down but I'd never seen the `int i = 0` trick. Thank you. I'll have to look into profiling...never done that.